# Flaskの複数のクエリパラメータの割当

Tags: python, flask

お世話になります。
パラメータ付きのURLを指定するとDBから情報を返すAPIを開発しています。
・実行環境
Centos7　64bit
Python3.6
virtualenv
Flask
環境構築済みですが、本番ではapahceで実行します。
・開発＆接続環境
Windows10
Chorme
Teratarm

今回は開発中のためデバックモードで実行しています。

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/query')
def func_query():
    args1 =  request.args.get('code')
    args2 =  request.args.get('name')
    print('args1:' + args1)
    print('args2:' + args2)
    return args1 + args2

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

本来はここから追加の処理をする予定です。

python app.py

ブラウザから下記URLにアクセスすると
http://localhost/query?code=123?name=sample

実行すると

コンソールでは

> args1:123?name=sample
>   args2:None

と表示されます。
変数に思った割当ができない状態になっています。
request.args.getは?を区切り文字として使用できると認識していましたが、違うのでしょうか？

質問のためにプログラムを縮小しながら記載しているため、記載ミスがあるかもしれません。
不明瞭な箇所があれば対応いたします。

以上です、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アクセスするURLが間違っていました。
この場合は

```
http://localhost/query?code=123&name=sample
```

とすれば目的の割当をすることができました。